# How a rest server should manage user enabling?

Tags: java, reactjs, design-patterns

I have a rest java backend that use javaee 7 and a react/redux application.
The same application is used by n different customer.
Each customer can ask for m roles that are different from the roles of the other customers.
One customer can, for example, pay to see a column in a list that shouldn't be visible for another customer.
The question is.. Is there a pattern or a method to handle in a light way the possibilities to hide or show columns in a list, or hide/show field in a form ? (user enablings)

CUSTOMER X pay to see the phone number in customer list

CUSTOMER Y should not see at all, the phone number.

The application released for both is the same.

How the server should give this information to the frontend application without coupling with it?

Thanks.

**Added one more question later:**

> *Yes, the react part is clear. I will add some information to be more clear. The point is "If I want to hide the phone Number field from the creation form?" How the server should give this information, to the front end? Should It send an empty data object?*

Comment: This is part of Java authentication and authorization. One approach is when your user logs into your application the UI can either pass the user or user token to back end every-time it makes a call and back end can determine if it should send phone number or not based on that user and its associated role.

Comment: Could you answer also to the second question?

Comment: I am more inclined to have server not to send phone number if user is not permitted to see it. This way if we have more than one client the server will not allow any of them to display the phone number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simplified example but it should give you a basic idea on how to conditionally fetch and render data based on user role.

1. *Front-end* calls API endpoint with auth data (`userId` and `token` in this example)
2. *Backend* determines role based on auth data, returns data related to this role (e.g. include `phone` if their role allows it)
3. *Front-end* renders response data (e.g. render `"Hidden"` if `phone` isn't present)

Here is how your `React` component may look:

```
class CustomerList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            customers: []
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        // fetch list data
        fetch('https://myapi.com/api/getCustomers', {userId: 12345, token: someToken})
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({customers: response.customers});
            });
    }
    render() {
        const { customers } = this.state;
        return (
            <div className="customers">
                {customers.length && 
                    <ul>
                        {customers.map(customer => (
                            <li>
                                <div className="name">
                                    Name: {customer.name}
                                </div>
                                <div className="phone">
                                    Phone: {customer.phone || "Hidden"}
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        ))}
                    </ul>
                }
                {!customers.length && 
                    <div>Loading...</div>
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Role is only one suggestion. There are other ways on the backend you may determine which data the current user has access to view. The point is that the data you return to the front-end should include only what the user has permission to view. You shouldn't return all the data and then conditionally render it on the front-end.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know some usefull pattern or idea to manage enablings in the back end? Do you usually divide them for each path?

Comment: And if I want to hide the phone Number field from the create form?  Thanks for your help

Comment: To render phone only when the data exists: `{customer.phone && <div>...</div>}`

Comment: Yes, the react part is clear. I will add some information to be more clear. The point is "If I want to hide the phone Number field from the creation form?" How the server should give this information, to the front end?Should  It send an empty data object?

Comment: I would just exclude the key from the response object. For example, `{"name": "Tom", "phone": "555-555-555"}` when phone is allowed and `{"name": "Tom"}` when it isn't.